# How to break while-loop in VFP (FoxPro) by button click?

Tags: loops, events, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to make simple FoxPro application with two buttons. First button starts while-loop and works correctly. Second button must break this loop. But I can't find any correctly working solution. 
 There are loop code:

```
DO WHILE !thisForm.cancelpressed

IF thisForm.cancelpressed
    EXIT
ENDIF

randNum=VAL(TRIM(STR(ROUND( 3*RAND(), 1))))
&&oneVar=VAL("1")

IF randNum = VAL("1")
    ThisForm.shape1.BackColor = greenColor
    ThisForm.shape2.BackColor = orangeColor
    ThisForm.shape3.BackColor = redColor
ENDIF

cs = seconds()
IF abs(cs - seconds()) >= 15
    doevents
    cs = seconds()
ENDIF

IF thisForm.cancelpressed
    EXIT
ENDIF

DOEVENTS
WAIT TIMEOUT 1   
ENDDO
```

This code is in the first button Click method. Form object have user-defined 'cancelpressed' property. In the second button click method I put this:

```
thisForm.cancelpressed = .T.
Thisform.Release()
Clear Events
```

But it not work. When loop started it dont want to listen any commands and clicks, and it dont let to close the program. Please help if you can

Comment: My program have two buttons and several shapes

Comment: If bind `thisForm.cancelpressed = .T.` to `MouseEnter` event for my-exit-button, than it works well. But it not click, it just hovering over my-exit-button

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting

```
Application.AutoYield = .T.
```

as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977324(v=vs.71).aspx

But if that doesn't work then I think you are stuck as VFP is not a true multithreaded application. You **might** be able to get around the problem using a timer object as per http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~TimerExample or using a multi threading workaround from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2006/05/16/create-multiple-threads-from-within-your-application/ but you would be very much on your own.

I have to say that starting a new application in VFP today probably isn't the best idea. There are plenty of current alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your wait window. Remove it.

```
Local greenColor, orangeColor, redColor
m.greenColor = 0x00FF00
m.orangeColor = 0x3060FF
m.redColor = 0xFF0000
Do While !Thisform.cancelpressed
    randNum=Val(Trim(Str(Round( 3*Rand(), 1))))

    If m.randNum = Val("1")
        Thisform.shape1.BackColor = m.greenColor
        Thisform.shape2.BackColor = m.orangeColor
        Thisform.shape3.BackColor = m.redColor
    Endif
    Doevents
Enddo
```

(I don't understand why you are doing such a weird randNum setting and check nor the purpose of setting the same colours again and again but it is not the point in this question)

Normally you should prefer using a Timer with a code like this.

And BTW this has nothing to do with multithreading neither in VFP nor in another language. You are simply doing a loop with a cancel flag check. Updating the UI, say in C#, with the same approach wouldn't be any easier.